# Move a character with touch buttons in unity

Tags: javascript, c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

I am creating a mobile game in Unity for Android Devices and my scene is basically with sprites, it is a 2D game. I know with the `input.GetAxis()` I can move my character but that is for desktop apps. I need to know how to get the axis for the horizontal movement and get that info and assign it to a mobile button

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Unity UI system together with an `EventSystem`. Create the Canvas and the `UnityUI.Button`s you want (an `EventSystem` and object should already be created), then add an `EventTrigger` component to the button with which you want to control the movement and hook the `OnPointerDown` (and also `OnPointerUp` if you want) event to some function your script. (List of events: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SupportedEvents.html). In that function you can then put your logic of controlling the player / movement.

This is also demonstrated in one of Unity's learning videos at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers.